# Security: How to show/hide, by password, QGroupBox in Qt App

Tags: c++, qt, root, usermode

I'm trying to prepare my Qt App (in C++) to be used by different user profiles: *root user* and *normal user*, so I want to hide specific root options (restricted QGroupBox) in *normal user* mode, and then when it's needed by a *root user* he could type it's password (in a security menu option, that I've already coded) to show them. Is that possible in the same GUI? I'm really stuck with this security implementation...

So, how could I code a hidden QGroupBox that will be shown only by *root user* when it's user/password is typed in the security menu option I mentioned before? How to implement that?

Is there an specific procedure in Qt to do that or any idea in other case?

Thanks a lot!

**Last Update**:
I've used the @The Badger suggestions and have a first version that works just about as I wanted.

Comment: Yes. It is possible. Your question is not clear: you stucked with `QComboBox` documentation or what?

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, I'm stucked with the security implementation (question edited)... As for how to prepare hidden options that will be shown when password is typed. How to implement that?

Comment: Once again: you don't know conditions operators like `if`? `if ( is_admin ) fillComboWithAdminItems(); else fillComboWithoutAdminItems();` Or what? Please, read, how to ask questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm sorry @SaZ maybe it's my fault around my poor explanation. I'm asking about an specific procedure to do that (if exists) or any idea in other case obviously I'm able to use a condition operators by myself without ask for help. For example, it was an incredible help for me the second part of The Badger answer, about connect a signal. Anyway thanks for your help and interest SaZ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options:

Each time before the widget is drawn/shown, check what level of access the user has and depending on that show or hide controls:

```
void MyWidget::showEvent(QShowEvent * event) {
    if(d_admin == true) {
        ui->myAdminEdit->setVisible(true);
    } else {
        ui->myAdminEdit->setVisible(false);
    }
    /* Or one line */
    ui->myAdminButton->setVisible(d_admin);
}
```

Or you connect a signal to show all of the admin widgets based on status:

```
/* In some constructor */   
ui->myAdminEdit->setVisible(false);
ui->myAdminButton->setVisible(false);
connect(autClass, SIGNAL(adminLoggedIn(bool)), ui->myAdminEdit, SLOT(setVisible(bool)));
connect(autClass, SIGNAL(adminLoggedIn(bool)), ui->myAdminButton, SLOT(setVisible(bool)));

/* And then after authentication */
isAdmin = authenticate(username, password);
emit adminLoggedIn(isAdmin);
```

After the emit the widgets will become visible.